# PyCharm inspection during debug

Tags: debugging, pycharm

When running code in debug, PyCharm shows these inspections (in orange in the picture). I do not really use them (I don't even understand their point) and I would like to deactivate this. Is there an option for that?

[image]

I could not find any option for this in the settings and I don't even know the name of this feature.